# OnCurrent event firing when moving from first record to the last but not from last to the first

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have the code below which is supposed to enable and disable the amount field on the main form and the purchases and sales subforms based on the value in the transaction type field. Now it works perfectly on the forward run. I.e. as soon as the form is loaded and i am scrolling from the first record to the last. But as soon as i hit the last record and i am scrolling through the records from back to front, the amount field remains disabled (i.e. the code no longer runs) and I have to reload the form. Is there a way I can solve this? I would like the user to have a realtime response with respect to the enabling and disabling.

Please find a picture of the form just in case it helps visualize the scenario.

[image]

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

    Select Case Me.transactionType.Value
    Case 1
        Me.PurchaseOrderDetails_subform.Enabled = False
        Me.SalesOrderDetails_subform.Enabled = False

    Case 4
        Me.Amount.Enabled = False
        Me.PurchaseOrderDetails_subform.Enabled = False
        Me.SalesOrderDetails_subform.Enabled = True

    Case 2
        Me.Amount.Enabled = False
        Me.PurchaseOrderDetails_subform.Enabled = True
        Me.SalesOrderDetails_subform.Enabled = False

    Case 3
        Me.Amount.Enabled = False
        Me.PurchaseOrderDetails_subform.Enabled = False
        Me.SalesOrderDetails_subform.Enabled = True
    End Select
End Sub
```

I will truly appreciate your help.

Comment: If you say "scrolling", what exactly do you mean? *Moving* to the first record? So the navigation bar shows "1 of 6"?

Comment: @Andre Yes by Scrolling I mean moving from one record to the next either from 1 - 6 or from 6 - 1. The screen shown is just to show the form I am referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never enable that field, so you may need this modification:

```
Select Case Me.transactionType.Value
    Case 1
        Me.Amount.Enabled = True
        Me.PurchaseOrderDetails_subform.Enabled = False
        Me.SalesOrderDetails_subform.Enabled = False
```

Comment: Many thanks Gustav; this has worked. I was initially thinking the amount control will always be true automatically since it is true on form load. I recognize the error now. Thanks